# Inside a circle: Four triangles with equal area, 5 unknown angles

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, angle

In this circle, I have four triangles equal area:
$$A_1=A_2=A_3=A_4$$
and 5 unknown angles.Is it possible to find the value these angles?

> Given
>   $$\alpha=?$$
>   $$\beta=?$$
>   $$\gamma=?$$
>   $$\delta=?$$
>   $$\varepsilon=?$$

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Landuros I tried it by Inscribed angle. But I don't know how to use hint(equal area) .

Comment: The formula for the area of a triangle is $A=ab\sin(C)$. $a$ and $b$ are the sides and $C$ is the included angle. Now, if $a=b$ because they are radii, what does that say about the angle $C$? (Given that the areas are the same.)

Comment: @Landuros But we don't have all side of triangles.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the problem has a solution.  $A_1$ and $A_2$ trivially have the same area, because they have congruent bases and the same altitude.  And $A_3$ and $A_4$ both have free vertices, making it seemingly easy to fudge.  $\gamma$ is easy to compute since it subtends a quarter-circle, and $\alpha, \beta, \epsilon$ are all related to each other, but I don't know that there's any way to fix them.

Comment: There is nonunique solution. It is possible to find one of many cases - is this what you look for?

Comment: @BarzanHayati: What is the source of this problem? Is it a classroom/textbook exercise? an online challenge? something you invented? What makes you think that the angles might have specific values?

Comment: @Blue It was a classroom exercise. Teacher asked us to investigate possible solutions?

Comment: @BarzanHayati: Interestingly, when $\alpha=30^\circ$, all five angles are "nice". (The two unlabeled ones in $\triangle A_4$ aren't. Maybe that's why they're unlabeled!) I wonder if your teacher omitted an important condition that would have led to this particular configuration.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in @MatthewDaly's comment and [@RossMillikan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3332465/409), the configuration is not unique, so the values of the angles are not fixed.

Here's an animation taking $\alpha$ from $0^\circ$ to $45^\circ$.

[image]

There's no need to show $\triangle A_2$, whose area is automatically equal to that of $\triangle A_1$; also, $\angle \beta = \tfrac12\angle \alpha$, so no need to show that, either. I've also substituted an out-of-the-way angle for $\delta$ in $\triangle A_3$. (Retrieving $\delta$ is easy enough, I suspect.) And I've included the counterpart angle for $\triangle A_4$.

Answer (score 1):

Following Matthew Daly's comment there is not a unique answer to the problem.  $A_1$ and $A_2$ have the same area.  If we make $\alpha$ small, the area of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are also small.  We can then slide the point where $\delta$ is and the point of $A_4$ on the chord from angle $\beta$ to make the areas of $A_3$ and $A_4$ match $A_1$ and $A_2$.  There will be a solution for all $\alpha$ over a range starting at $0$. It stops when the sides of $A_3$ and $A_4$ pass through each other.  One could compute the angles where that happens, where the sides of $A_3$ and $A_4$ are coincident.

Answer (score 0):

The angles can be express in terms of $\alpha$:
$$\beta=\color{red}{0.5\alpha} \quad \text{(inscribed and central angles)}\\
\varepsilon=\color{red}{\frac12(90^\circ-\alpha)} \quad \text{(inscribed and central angles (which is complementary))}\\
\gamma=\color{red}{45^\circ} \quad \text{(inscribed angle and central angle of $90^\circ$)}\\
$$
Since $\beta+\varepsilon=45^\circ$, the longest side of $A_4$ can be found from the isosceles right triangle to be $R\sqrt{2}$.

The base of $A_4$ (call it $x$, which is equal to the base of $A_3$) can be expressed through area: 
$$S=\frac12R\sqrt{2}x\sin \varepsilon \Rightarrow x=\frac{\sqrt2S}{R\sin(45^\circ-0.5\alpha)}$$
The upper right side of $A_3$ (call it $y$) can be found from Cosine theorem:
$$y^2=2R^2-2R^2\sin (90^\circ-\alpha)$$
And finally, $\delta$ can be found from the Sine theorem:
$$\frac{y}{\sin \delta}=\frac{x}{\sin(\delta +45^\circ)}.$$
However, the solution looks cumbersome!